# Importing 3D models to represent physical devices in Azure Digital Twin

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

I am very new to Digital Twin and was just exploring Azure digital twin service. I went through some of the documentation and completed the tutorial on how to deploy Digital Twin and work with it. But I want to know how can we visualize physical entities in Digital Twin like any 3D models and interact with them. So I was just wondering is it possible to import any 3D models in azure Digital Twin and interact using any dashboards. If it can be done is there any reference documents or projects on this?

Answer (score 1):

Digital twins as a principle come in many shapes and forms, including 3D modelling. However, Azure Digital Twins is little more than a spatial graph with some ingress and egress endpoints. However, it is possible to [upload blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-add-blobs) to an devices, spaces and users.

To enable your scenario, you can then retrieve the blobs in your (custom made) dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for your response.it gave me some idea to explore more on Digital Twin. But instead of custom dashboards, is there any Azure Platform where we can import 3D models?

Comment: Not that I know of, but [Azure Remote Rendering](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/remote-rendering/) is coming (private preview now).